# Why does the Greek letter lambda often get substituted for the letter A?

Tags: alphabet

It happens a lot with commercial products, for example the car company Kia.  Except they spell if Kappa Iota Lambda (KIL).  Why?  That is just one example among many I see nowadays.  Are all these companies just trying to be cute or is there something I don't know about?  Is it now acceptable to use lambda for A?

Edit:

This was originally a comment, but I thought it appropriate to edit the question.

If this is just one company's stylization then I would say it would be off-topic and would not have asked the question.  But I see this EVERYWHERE.

Duncan Donuts stylized the word doughnut, but now, "donut" is considered an acceptable spelling.  And that's just one company.  And phonetically, it's correct.  "Nite" for night is used too, and it's phonetically correct as well.

If Duncan Donut's stylization can change the English language, why can't the use of lambda (and yes, folks, it is a lambda) lead to a change as well?  I don't think people are appreciating the ubiquity of this "stylization."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but this is a question about design, not about English. They aren't spelling with a lambda, they're substituting a standard *A* for a highly stylized one that resembles a lambda, much like the Waldorf Astoria hotel was stylized *Waldorf゠Astoria*, or how *EMC* was stylized *EMC²*.

Comment: The rendering of A without a cross-bar is just a stylistic feature. Lambda is unknown to the majority of English readers so the possibility of confusion is only small.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an incorrect premise (stylised design mistaken as a Greek letter) and is therefore not about English language/usage at all.

Comment: And, likewise, the [Toys“R”Us logo](https://sea.mashable.com/culture/3052/jobless-man-stole-more-than-us700-toys-from-toys-r-us-for-his-two-kids) isn’t using the Cyrillic letter Ya (Я). Sometimes a backward “R” is just a backward “R”.

Comment: @Scott That's just one company's stylization.   What I am calling attention to is a trend that goes beyond just one company's unique stylization.

Comment: Mods, can this be changed to a community wiki post?  I have a feeling this might be of use to people in the future.  I understand the point people are making that it is off topic, but it should not go down the memory hole.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not characterize it as a lambda. As far as I am aware, almost any English speaker will tell you that it is a stylized "A". It  is acceptable to alter the look of some letters for logos when it is clear enough what the letter represents.

There is no letter in the English alphabet that could be confused with an "A" without the cross-bar. I would go as far to say that most people would see it as an upside-down "V" before saying it was a Lambda.